# In OAuth 2 why is there need for an Access Token when there is the Authorization Code?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, cryptography, authorization

In OAuth 2 the client app exchanges an authorization code for an access token. And with the access token, the app can make API calls. However, I don't really get why OAuth 2 has this step; it seems like an extra step.

One reason I can think of is that the authorization code is given through a redirect call on the client side, so it has the potential to be compromised, thus it's short lived; whereas the access token is given server-to-server.

That is true, but there is also the secret API key that the app sends. Then why couldn't same be done with the authorization code?

Say there was no access token but just the authorization code. Then even if someone gets the authorization code, they wouldn't be able to do anything if the OAuth server also checked the secret key along with the authorization code.

It should allow the OAuth server to:

1. Make sure the request was made by the correct app (authenticate)
2. Determine what types of permission were granted (authorize)

Answer (score 1):

Ability to get access_token directly (Implicit grant type)  is required in the cases of JavaScript clients or web applications running in a browser. Because, these clients are not secure based on the options available for saving the client secret. The client id and secret are required to exchange authorization code for an access_token.

These two grant types exist to provide various levels of security when implementing authentication.

If the resource served by the API is extremely sensitive then you want at most security, which is provided by Authorization Code flow. In this grant type you validate the client (server side API or a mobile client) and the resource owner (user) before granting access to the resource. The access_token is not even exposed to the browser/ user (since a stolen token can give access to the resource), thus giving high degree of security. This flow is complex and involves more round trips to the authorization server, but, provides more security.

If you don't need that kind of security on a resource you can use Implicit grant type where the browser/ user has access to the token. This flow is simple with only one trip to authorization server. It will not validate the client. No need to save the client secret with the browser.

Hopefully this makes sense. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: But **why** authorization code and access token are required for server based flow, i know it's for security,  but why just "authorization code" + "secret key" are **not** enough.

Comment: I understand in Client Side only apps you can't safely store "secret key". But neither is "access token" stored there in normal authentication flow. So i wonder why you even mentioned it.

Comment: Also please stay away from discussion on what is best authentication flow for sensitive data vs non sensitive. I am purely asking about Oauth 2 flow.

Comment: May be my explanation is little off, sorry for that. Let me try this explanation. Secret key is per client and can not have a payload like access_token. With access_token you can have payload, which could be helpful in scenarios where you want to pass extra information related to authorization along with the token.

Comment: Client Id and secret could be used as part of Client Credentials Flow, to get access to protected resources that are under the control of client. But, with an access_token the access can be restricted to  fewer resources only, thus the impact of comprise is less. Hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Secret is secret because it's per client, unique to App. I dont know what you mean by payload, it's upto server to respond with whatever it wants. Also I have not said secret key helps identify scope of access, what i am saying is that authorization code contains scope of access but why do we exchange it for access token.

Comment: From my understanding, the Oauth 2 spec is designed to unify the authorization process. Irrespective of the flow used, ultimately access_token is what provides access to a resource. If we use "authorization code + security key" then we are deviating from access_token for resource access. Plus, authorization code can also be used to add additional security measures.

Comment: Also the validation logic at the consuming end needs no change as we always send access_token only for authorization. If we use access_token some times and combination of auth code + secret sometimes, the validation logic has to change based on what's coming in.

Comment: i am aware of oauth2 flow

Comment: After reading the spec again it does look like the "exchange step" is not necessary. Since the spec doesn't talk about how the token validation is done and the type of the token used, may be a JWT is used as access_token and the token validation is done locally instead of making a trip to auth server for every request. Again, this comment doesn't explain why the extra step. Thank you.

Comment: it's ok, you do have a good grasp of ever step, better than me. but i wanted to know security/use case reasons behind one approach maybe someone will come eventually and explain.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer do you think the security cause could be to avoid using the secret key for every request validation?

Comment: no, if it's backend only. as if there were 10000 users' visits each would need secret key with their token retrieval.